# Sprout plugin: Send information in AJAX success response

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, plugin-sproutforms

I'm using Sprout for registering to events, I want to be able to send a code in the AJAX response when EVENT_AFTER_SAVE occurs. At the moment, I get `{success: true}` back, but I want to be able to get `{success: true, code: "XXXXX"}` after save

The code will be coming from a Channel called Tokens, which consists of one field: tokenCode. I want to grab one at random and send tokenCode as "code"

This is what I want my AJAX request to be, note `var redirect = '' + data.token`

```
$('#token-form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // prepare some variables
  var postUrl = 'sprout-forms/entries/save-entry';
  var formData = $(this).serialize();

// process the form
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : postUrl,
    data : formData,
    dataType : 'json',
    encode : true
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    if (data.success == true)
    {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(data);

      var redirect = '' + data.token
      $(location).attr('href', redirect);
    }

  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the value `code` coming from? Is it part of the data model that is saved?

Comment: I see in a separate comment you've said that the code is coming from a Craft Entry. When and where does the code get created? Can you elaborate on the full workflow in your question?

Comment: No, it's be coming from an Entry, theres a channel call "tokens", I'll be wanting to get one at random and then pass a field to code

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Why do you need this in the AJAX response? Can you just grab a random token on the page when you load the page or thank you page?

Comment: Because the token is a unique variable which needs to be appended a string to make up a redirect url so something like http://mywebsite.com?token=xxxxx

Is it possible to send this token back in the AJAX response?

I'll updated the question too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93096/discussion-between-hassan-mahmood-and-ben-parizek).

Comment: I still don't understand why the token needs to be part of the URL. I don't see a way to comment in the linked chat. Please drop me a note at sprout@barrelstrengthdesign.com if you want to continue the thread elsewhere or ping me on Craft Discord and happy to discuss further.